# Single page web app router with css3 transations

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, css-transitions, single-page-application

Does someone know good library for routing with css3 transations for single page web apps.
Here is good library for Zepto https://github.com/dgileadi/zepto-page-transitions, I'm looking similar solution, but only for jquery or without any javascript librarys.

I know I could use jquery mobile, but I just need the page css3 transations, and thats why it feels to heavy.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can customize your jquerymobile download http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Comment: this could be solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Durandaljs

[Durandaljs](http://durandaljs.com/) is a fantastic library for SPAs.  It uses jQuery and Knockoutjs and has a bunch of features to make building spas simpler.  It has plugins for a [router](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Router/) which wraps sammyjs. Also, it has a nice plugin for [CSS transitions](https://gist.github.com/evanlarsen/4799019).